# Wildcard star not working in GDAL 3.3.3

Tags: gdal, wildcard

Using GDAL 3.3.3 on my windows 10 workstation I cannot use the wildcard *. With my old windows 7 workstation I used to be able to include the wildcard to search for all tiff files in a directory by using `.\*.tif`

My command is: `gdaltindex envelope.shp .\*.tif`

Since I have updated this does not work. Did I install GDAL wrong, is this a bug, or has it been phased out?

Comment: that sounds like an operating system issue - does `ls *.tif` still work?

Comment: Yes. This still works.

Comment: then you'll need to tell us more about your operating system and the exact command you are running

Comment: Typical use case would be to merge multiple tifs which are all in one directory - gdal_merge.py -o out.tif .\*.tif

Comment: My understanding is that gdal tools rely on the shell expanding the wildcard, (which Windows does not do). There are some powershell workarounds, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897242/powershell-wildcards-in-passing-filenames-as-arguments

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for me was to parenthesise the wildcard with

```
(get-item .\*.tif)
```

I can now put this in a gdal command such as

```
gdaltindex shapefile.shp (get-item .\*.tif)
```